# adding multiple reactions to embed

Tags: c#, discord.net

I know the title sounds kinda like some other things, but my issue is kinda... Weird? Idk. I'm making a poll command, and everything is working atm. But I want to make it so instead of just automatically adding four reaction options, it counts the options, and adds the reacts based on that. I've got it working (to an extent), but it kept error 400'ing. Instead of making it react, I made it tell me how many reacts it was adding... It was adding 36 reactions at 8 options. Code and result below.

Code:

```
        public async Task MakePoll(IMessageChannel channel, string title, string description, [Remainder] string choices)
        {

            string[] options = choices.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var zero = new Emoji($"{734770204311027712}");
            var one = new Emoji("1️⃣");
            var two = new Emoji("2️⃣");
            var three = new Emoji("3️⃣");

            var emotes = (zero, one, two, three );

            var choicecount = options.Count() - 1;

            int reactioncount = choicecount;

            var poll = new EmbedBuilder();
            poll.WithTitle(title);
            poll.WithDescription(description);
            for (int a = 0; a <= choicecount; a++)
            {
                poll.AddField($"{a}", $"{options[a].ToString()}");
            }
            
            var derp = await channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, poll.Build());

            for (int b = 1; b < reactioncount; b++)
            {
                //await derp.AddReactionsAsync(had an array of emotes, plugged it in here. just haven't added it back after ctrl+z spam.);
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{b} emotes tried to add");
            }

        }
```

Result: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/689738717589798913/735340372838056026/unknown.png

Comment: I'm confused, based on the commented out line, were you adding an array of reactions withing the loop? If you then that's clearly your problem. The loop should be adding one reaction per iteration or you should have an array with the expected amount of reactions an that array would be used outside of a loop.

Comment: I was. Mainly trying to figure out how to add a reaction for each poll option, being a different number in correspondence to the poll option. Say there's 7 options defined, my goal is to have it know that, and then react with 0-6 for votes.

It's just not liking the idea much.

Comment: I gave you two options in my response

Answer (score 0):

In you current implementation, the for loop is your main issue. If your array has 4 items, you'd loop 4 times and add 4 reactions each loop (4x4). If you are using `AddReactions` it should be called once, not within a loop.

```cs
public async Task MakePoll(IMessageChannel channel, string title, string description, [Remainder] string choices)
{
    //code to declare emotes, create and send embed

    //Add reactions to the sent message
    for (int b = 1; b < reactioncount; b++)
    {
        await derp.AddReactionsAsync(emotes); //this adds 4 reactions every time you loop, you don't want that
    }
    //ideally, within your loop you would have been selecting the array indexes that
    //should be used. That is, if you created an array with emotes 0-9, but you only 
    //have 6 options you would loop through the options and call AddReaction 
    //not AddReactions... passing the reaction at position 0, position 1 and so on 
    //up to position 6.
}
```

Option 1: Dynamically create a list of the emotes that should be added and call `AddReactionsAsync` without looping

```cs
public async Task MakePoll(IMessageChannel channel, string title, string description, [Remainder] string choices)
{
    string[] options = choices.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var choicecount = options.Count() - 1;
    var poll = new EmbedBuilder();
    var emotes = new List<Emoji>();
    
    poll.WithTitle(title);
    poll.WithDescription(description);
    
    for (int a = 0; a <= choicecount; a++)
    {
        poll.AddField($"{a}", $"{options[a].ToString()}");
        emotes.Add(new Emoji($"{a}\u20e3")); //add an emoji for each poll option
    }
    
    var derp = await channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, poll.Build());

    //here we do NOT loop the adding of reactions when adding from an array
    await derp.AddReactionsAsync(emotes.ToArray);
}
```

Option 2: Loop through the number of options and call `AddReaction` to add the dynamically created reaction

```cs
public async Task MakePoll(IMessageChannel channel, string title, string description, [Remainder] string choices)
{
    string[] options = choices.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var choicecount = options.Count() - 1;
    var poll = new EmbedBuilder();
    
    poll.WithTitle(title);
    poll.WithDescription(description);
    
    for (int a = 0; a <= choicecount; a++)
    {
        poll.AddField($"{a}", $"{options[a].ToString()}");
    }
    
    var derp = await channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, poll.Build());

    //If you are looping, you should use the singular AddReactionAsync
    for (int b = 1; b = options.count; b++)
    {
        await derp.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji($"{b}\u20e3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, now that makes sense! Not even gonna lie here, I didn't know about the \u20e3 thing, so I was trying to hard define a set of emotes to use and then use that. Now I see what you mean about the use of arrays when doing this, though. Thanks, my dude :o